# How to linked datasets in csv file with RDF Ontology?

Tags: python, rdf, ontology, knowledge-graph

I wanted to link the datasets of Adobe's Security Advisory product that in *.CSV* format with the ontology that I already created, the example of datasets looks like this:

| Text | Label |
| --- | --- |
| APSA08-05 | SecAdvisoryID |
| APSB12-09 | BulletinID |

Here is the simple ontology that I created using **WebOWL tool** :

[image]

For the ontology , I use **RDFlib** in **Python**. Here is the code of the ontology:

```
from rdflib import Graph, Namespace
from rdflib.namespace import RDF, XSD, RDFS
from rdflib.term import Literal

#create the graph
graph = Graph()
test = Namespace("http://example.org/cyber/test#")
graph.bind("test", test)

graph.add((test.SecAdvisoryID, RDF.type, RDFS.Class))
graph.add((test.BulletinID, RDF.type, RDFS.Class))

graph.add((test.hasTitle, RDFS.domain, test.SecAdvisoryID))
graph.add((test.hasTitle, RDFS.domain, test.BulletinID))

graph.add((test.hasBulletin, RDFS.domain, test.SecAdvisoryID)) 
graph.add((test.hasBulletin, RDFS.range, test.BulletinID))
graph.add((test.hasAdvisory, RDFS.domain, test.BulletinID)) 
graph.add((test.hasAdvisory, RDFS.range, test.SecAdvisoryID))

# save the graph
with open("testgraph.ttl", "wb") as f:
    f.write(graph.serialize(format="turtle"))
```

I saved it in *.ttl* (turtle) format.

Output of the *testgraph.ttl* :

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix test: <http://example.org/cyber/test#> .

test:BulletinID a rdfs:Class .

test:SecAdvisoryID a rdfs:Class .

test:hasAdvisory rdfs:domain test:BulletinID ;
    rdfs:range test:SecAdvisoryID .

test:hasBulletin rdfs:domain test:SecAdvisoryID ;
    rdfs:range test:BulletinID .

test:hasTitle rdfs:domain test:BulletinID,
        test:SecAdvisoryID .
```

My intention is to make a knowledge graph of security advisory, knowledge that I crawled is from Adobe's Security Advisory. Hence, my problem is how I want to make sure that the ontology will recognize the datasets?

Comment: What do you mean by the ontology recognising the dataset? You need to first figure out what exactly is in each cell of the csv. From what I see, the first column is id and the second one is type. I would suggest creating the ontology with types, annotations and the general hierarchy before adding restrictions like domain and range. It would be easier to debug. Aldo don’t forget annotations they are pretty important and don’t Cary much computational weight for reasoners.

Comment: I want the output to be *APSA08-05* hasbulletin *APSB12-09* and *APSB12-09* hasAdvisory *APSA08-05* in a graph. I mean do I need to do manually to link the entity using ontology? and how?

Comment: Yes, you need to manually create them. If you don't want to do it in Python, you can also use Tarql[https://tarql.github.io]

Answer (score 1):

The [CSV on the Web](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-primer/) specifications provide a means of generically mapping [CSV to RDF](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-csv2rdf-20151217/) using a [metadata file](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-metadata/) to describe relationships.

While there is vocabulary associated with the metadata file, the format allows any vocabulary to be used in the metadata.

To date, I know of no Python implementation, but my on [Ruby implementation](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdf-tabular) is fully compatible with the specs, and can be tested online at http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/distiller.

Comment: Hi Gregg, thanks for making that spec, it looks really handy for my use-case. Is there an RDF namespace of the spec?

Comment: The csvw namespace is http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#. All described in https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-metadata/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-tabular-data-model-20151217/.